# TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable - Rolling window - Python

Tags: python, pandas, series, statsmodels, rolling-computation

I have an Hodrick-Prescott (HP) function defined in Python as follows:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

def func_HP(close, params):
    cycle,trend = sm.tsa.filters.hpfilter(close,params)
    return trend
```

If i apply that function to a column present in a datafrate like this:

```
df['Trend'] = func_HP(df['Close'],18000)
```

it works fine and I get the Trend value for the whole "static" column.

I want to apply the HP function to a rolling window of the column df['Close']. The window length is 240. As such, the HP filter will be applied to the rolling 240 records. 
I have used this code:

```
x = df.rolling(window=240, min_periods=240, on='Close').apply(func_HP(df['Close'],18000))
```

but I get the error:

> TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

I guess that is because once you apply the rolling window the column `df['Close']` becomes an array: is that right?

And what can I do to "convert" the outcome of the rolling selection to a column?

Comment: If you are using external libraries (as it seems based on your code), please include them in the tags of the question. Most widely used libraries have a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it looks like the hp_filter function returns an array. So you'd need to add something like:

```
def func_HP(close, params):
    cycle,trend = sm.tsa.filters.hpfilter(close,params)
    df_trend = pd.dataframe(trend)
    return df_trend
```